# Shell script to count the number of different vowels in a text file

Tags: shell-script

I'm working on a script that should take a given text file and figure out how many characters, vowels, and how many of each vowel is present. The first part was easy but I'm having problems with the loop. My understanding is that the myString count becomes the loop count. Each time it reads a character it goes through the if/elif statements and when it matches a vowel, it increases the value of that vowel's corresponding variable by 1.

Shellcheck.net doesn't like my lines but I'm not understanding why:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

myString=$(cat sampletext.txt | tr A-Z a-z)   #this works
count=$(echo -n "$myString" |tr -d '[.]'| wc -c)    #this works
vowels=$(echo -n $myString | tr -cd 'aeiou'| wc -c) #this works

va=0
ve=0
vi=0
vo=0
vu=0
i=0
while (( i++ < ${#myString} )); do
char=$(expr substr "$myString" "$i" 1)
if   [ "$char" -eq "a" ]; then
((va=++))
elif [ "$char" -eq "e" ]; then
((ve=++))
elif [ "$char" -eq "i" ]; then
((vi=++))
elif [ "$char" -eq "o" ]; then
((vo=++))
elif [ "$char" -eq "u" ]; then
((vu=++))
fi
done
echo $vi
```

Shellcheck output:

```
((va=++))
^-- SC1105 (error): Shells disambiguate (( differently or not at all. For subshell, add spaces around ( . For ((, fix parsing errors.
  ^-- SC2030 (info): Modification of va is local (to subshell caused by (..) group).
```

*My bad, I only put in the part that wasn't working. I've edited this to show the whole thing including the shebang =)

Comment: Have you defined your script's shell with something like `#!/path/to/shell` on the first line?

Comment: Four immediate fixes: (1) Add a shebang. (2) The increment operator is just `(( va++ ))` -- no `=` needed. (3) Text comparisons use `=` not `-eq`. (4) Shell has built-in substitutions for substrings -- no need to run an external command per character. Repost when shellcheck is clean.

Comment: @Paul, add that as an answer

Comment: Why not `grep -io '[aeiou]' input.txt | wc -l` for all vowels, and more constrained patterns for each specific vowel?

Comment: Or more generally: `grep -o | tr | sort | uniq -c`

Comment: I could grep the whole thing but I want to learn/understand how to use loops for some of the reports I want to make for work.

Comment: @Geordie : You had good feedback from your previous two questions, but don't seem to have applied that help here.

Comment: @roaima  All the answers in that link make extensive use of external commands (some of the once per character): so not ideal for a Bash learning example. As usual, I have polished a pure bash version beyond recognition: not suitable for a homework question, but (I hope) a helpful example to analyse and learn from.

Comment: I'm curious: can you explain what `tr -d '[.]'` does?

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Thanks Paul (and everyone)! As soon as I got rid of the = in front of my variables and changed -eq to =, it worked. I play around with this a bit more and then ask one of my netadmins if I can get access to the linux test server to poke around in a bit. I'm waaaay too fresh for the live server =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash comes with a 190-page manual, which has a Contents List and several indexes (in appendix D). The (somewhat obscure and horrible) syntax hides a lot of power.

Most of the answer/tutorial here depends on these sections.

[www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays)

[www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Arrays are nothing special: they are simply the lazy person's way to avoid inventing a lot of similar names for a group of variables. Think of the index value as the last part of the name. But because the index is a variable itself, it is an excellent tool for loops.

This is the script, hopefully with enough comments to show the intentions:

```
#! /bin/bash

myString="The quick brown FOX jumps over the lazy dog."

Vowel=( a e i o u )     #.. Declare a list of what we want to output. 

myString="${myString,,}"    #.. Shell substitution to lowercase a string. 

#.. Declares an associative array to store character frequencies.
#.. Typical values would be: Freq[e]="3", Freq[h]="2", Freq[q]="1".
#.. We store counts for all characters, to avoid multiple tests.

declare -A Freq 

#.. Iterate the string, indexing via a substring expansion,
#.. and counting the frequencies of each ASCII character.

for (( j = 0; j < ${#myString}; j++ )); do
    (( Freq[\${myString:j:1}]++ ))
done

declare -p Freq     #.. Debug of the frequency array.

#.. Iterate over the vowel list to report the frequencies.

for v in "${Vowel[@]}"; do
    printf 'Vowel %s occurs %2d times.\n' "${v}" "${Freq["${v}"]}"
done
```

This is the output:

```
$ time ./Calhoun.sh
declare -A Freq=([" "]="9" [.]="1" 
    [a]="1" [b]="1" [c]="1" [d]="1" 
    [e]="3" [f]="1" [g]="1" [h]="2" [i]="1" 
    [j]="1" [k]="1" [l]="1" [m]="1" [n]="1" 
    [o]="4" [p]="1" [q]="1" [r]="2" [s]="1" 
    [t]="2" [u]="2" [v]="1" [w]="1" [x]="1" 
    [y]="1" [z]="1" )
Vowel a occurs  1 times.
Vowel e occurs  3 times.
Vowel i occurs  1 times.
Vowel o occurs  4 times.
Vowel u occurs  2 times.

real    0m0.013s
user    0m0.012s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Comment: See [How to use associative arrays safely inside arithmetic expressions?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/627474). You'd need `(( Freq[\${myString:j:1}]++ ))` or you'd have problems with strings that contain backslashes, quotes, backticks, `]`, `@`, `*` at least.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas  Thanks for that life-saver -- including `]` in the input does indeed throw a syntax error. While I was testing that, I noticed I was also not even counting `space`, because my Bash silently ignores an empty index. Not my best day.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to provide an `awk` based solution, since [you mention](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/681281/shell-script-to-count-the-number-of-different-vowels-in-a-text-file?noredirect=1#comment1287349_681281) that you want to "*learn/understand how to use loops for some of the reports I want to make"*, and often `awk` is more efficient for this kind of situation than pure `bash`

```
#!/bin/sh
#
grep -o -- . "$1" |
    awk '
        /[[:alpha:]]/ { letters[tolower($1)]++ }
        /[aeiou]/ { vowels++ }

        END {
            printf "%d\tvowels\n", vowels;
            for (letter in letters) {
                printf "%d\t%s\n", letters[letter], letter | "sort -k2,3"
            }
        }
    '
```

Call the file `letters` and make it executable (`chmod a+x letters`). If the input file is `sampletext.txt` you can run it like this

```
./letters sampletext.txt
```

Notes

- `grep -o -- . {file}` (assuming GNU `grep` or compatible) splits the file into individual characters, one per line. We could do this inside `awk` itself but this is a quick (and lazy) approach
- `[[:alpha:]]` matches an alphabetic character. You could use `[[:alnum:]]` for alphanumerics, or `.` for any character
- the `printf | "sort"` construct feeds all its formatted output into (a single instance of) the `sort` command, which in turn sorts on column 2 according to your current locale

Comment: "awk is more efficient": Have to admit, most of my Bash functions are three lines of Bash wrapping 40 lines of awk. Apart from being consistently 50+ times faster, awk's syntax is much more forgiving and less full of special characters. Readability reveals bugs.

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
myString="Hello WORLD"
declare -A vowel=()      # an associative array
declare -l char          # value is lowercased upon assignment

for ((i=0; i<${#myString}; i++)); do 
    char=${myString:i:1}

    # inside [[...]], the == operator does _pattern matching_
    [[ $char == [aeiou] ]] && ((vowel[$char]++))
done

declare -p vowel   # => ([o]="2" [e]="1" )
```

The more efficient way to loop over the chars of a string (especially if the string can be long) is

```bsh
while IFS= read -r -d '' -n1 char; do 
    [[ $char == [aeiou] ]] && ((vowel[$char]++))
done < <(
    printf '%s' "$myString"
)
```

If you want to include vowels with count zero:

```bsh
myString="Hello WORLD"
declare -A vowel=([a]=0 [e]=0 [i]=0 [o]=0 [u]=0)
declare -l char

while IFS= read -r -d '' -n1 char; do 
    [[ -v "vowel[$char]" ]] && ((vowel[$char]++))
done < <(printf '%s' "$myString")

for char in "${!vowel[@]}"; do
    printf '%s\t%d\n' "$char" "${vowel[$char]}"
done | sort
```

````
a   0
e   1
i   0
o   2
u   0```
````

Comment: +1 for that `read -n1` idiom, and another for the lower-case by attribute `-l`.

Answer (score 0):

Pure `awk`-solution for each vowel separately.

```
#define array vowels with one vowel for each index
BEGIN{ split("aeiou",vowels,"") }

#in each line, make line lowercase
{$0=tolower($0)
#for each vowel occurence (loops through array vowels),
#replace vowel with empty string.
#gsub returns the number of replacements is has made,
#this value is added to the counter array element for each vowel
for (letter in vowels) { count[letter]+=gsub(vowels[letter],"") } }

#in the end, loop through array vowels and return vowel and counter value
END { for (letter in vowels) {print vowels[letter],count[letter]} }
```

Save this as e.g. `count_vowels.awk` and run via

```
awk -f count_vowels.awk inputfile.txt
```

`#`-lines are comments and may be omitted.